# Rounded corner colored box around figure

Tags: floats, color, boxes

I'm trying to get Rounded corner grey-colored box around figures.
One solution would be to use

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

but this results in black box around a figure. What would be the
way to proceed?

Comment: You can try [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).

Comment: BTW, [welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The `fancybox` package provides a `\ovalbox` macro which might be useful here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define your own `\floatstyle`.  In this case I took the definition from [the `float` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float) and adjusted it to use [the `mdframed` package environment](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) to draw the frame.

Here is a comparison of using `\floatstyle{boxed}` and `\floatstyle{myRoundBox}`:

[image]

### Note:

- I took the liberty to add a background color, and `tikzsetting` to illustrate some of the customization that are possible -- see the `mdframed` documentation for more options.
- Updated to incorporate  Torbjørn T.'s suggestion of adding a `\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}` in `\def\@fs@mid{}` as per [How to frame a figure in Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184853/how-to-frame-a-figure-in-lyx).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFigureBoxStyle}{backgroundcolor=yellow!10,, roundcorner=25pt,tikzsetting={draw=blue, line width=1pt}}%

\makeatletter
  \newcommand\fs@myRoundBox{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\begin{mdframed}[style=myFigureBoxStyle]}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}%
  \def\@fs@post{\end{mdframed}}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{myRoundBox} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\section{Using boxed}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{../images/EiffelTall}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\floatstyle{myRoundBox} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\section{Using myRoundBox}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{../images/EiffelTall}
    \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I [just used your answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184853/how-to-frame-a-figure-in-lyx), a thought came up: If you add something like `\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}` in `\def\@fs@mid{}` you get some space between image and caption.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Good point. Have incorporated your suggestions.