# When to indent a paragraph?

Tags: floats, indentation, paragraphs, typography

I use indentation of the first line for paragraphs. When a new paragraph starts after a code listing (or some other figure), this looks a bit unpleasant to me. What is the typographical convention for this? Is it OK to use `\noindent` to supress the indentation?

Comment: I typically add comments between figures and the text so that `TeX` will know it is not a new paragraph. If that doesnt do, I will move the figure. This clears up the look in the file and you will not do any local fixes.

Comment: I think what is happening is that since it is difficult to tell if the text following a figure is a new paragraph, an indent is added. If it should not be a new paragraph then certainly `\noindent` would be correct.

Comment: If the text after the list/display and the list/display itself [is in the same paragraph as] the text before the list/display, you don't indent. Otherwise, you indent. Without this convention, your readers won't know the difference between a start of a new paragraph or a continuation of the current paragraph.

Comment: Marc's right. Try [adding a background to your figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure) or [using parskip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r); that may look better to you.

Comment: Further to `rds`'s suggestion, you could also indent the listing.

Comment: I would suggest that if you put something "on display", which means that 1) it is not a floating object but 2) it is a standalone one or several lines of text, one of the good ways is indent the whole text, like in the [quote environment](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/environ.htm#quote)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typographical convention is to indent the paragraph following a figure (even a display figure). The reason is simple, suppose you have a figure on top of the page and text underneath it, there is nothing signalling that this is the beginning of a new paragraph or the start of a sentence from a paragraph that ended at the previous page. (La)TeX incorporates paragraph indentation in this fashion as a default.

Even when images are placed in the middle, it is good typography to be consistent and they do not look "out of place", if you treat the figures properly. Here is such an example from a statistics book.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

`\noindent` would work but actually latex goes to a lot of trouble working out if figures and displayed lists etc are between paragraphs or mid-paragraph, and not indenting in the latter case. So if you are getting indentation where you don't want it, then probably you have spurious blank line somewhere signaling the start of a paragraph at a point that you want to consider mid-paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree entirely with David Carlisle's answer, when it comes to reading my own `.tex` files, /I/ like to have some blank space between the start and end of a list or figure or table (etc., etc.) since I find it makes for better reading of the `.tex.  file.  But you certainly don't want to 'start' a new paragraph where it is inappropriate.  So I usually do one of two things:

```
paragraph text:
%
%
\begin{itemize}
...
\end{itemize}
%
%
resumption of paragraph text....
```

or I use `\noindent` and use plain blank lines to break everything up.  I am not consistent across documents, but I tend to be consistent within a document as to which one I use.

Comment: Depending on your settings, leaving a blank line will also change spacing. I'm not sure how lists are handled, but it can definitely change how math is displayed.

Comment: @Caramdir -- a fair point.  I never do math so I have no idea what effect my 'solution' would have.