# How to set a background color of figure environment?

Tags: floats, color

Currently I've this situation:

```
\newenvironment{inline}[2]{
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \caption{#1}\label{#2}
    \vspace{10pt}%
}{
  \end{figure}
}
```

How can I set a background color to whole content, which is in the figure?

Comment: Does this question help: [Rounded corner colored box around figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure), or is this a duplicate?

Comment: Note that line breaks in the source code will be converted to spaces, if they are not following a macro (without arguments) or are commented out using `%`. You should therefore always write `{%` instead if `{` at the end of a line.

Comment: Also figure caption belong usually below the image, not above. You should change the values of `\abovecaptionskip` (usually 10pt) and `\belowcaptionskip` (usually 0pt) if you want to have it the other way.

Comment: Many thanks to you @MartinScharrer for your further advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`mdframed` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) for this. In the below MWE, I've added an option first argument to the `inline` environment which specifies the `backgroundcolor` (default is `black!25` = 25% black):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newenvironment{inline}[3][black!25]{
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=#1]
    \centering\caption{#2}\label{#3}
    \vspace{10pt}%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
  \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{inline}{An image}{image}
  \rule{150pt}{100pt}
\end{inline}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I've only added the `backgroundcolor` option to `mdframed`, leaving all the other settings as is (for example, it includes a border). Read the [`mdframed` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) on how to modify any default settings.

Having a caption above the figure, you may be interested in adjusting the lengths `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` to suit your needs - they are set with the caption-below-float in mind. The defaults are `10pt` and `0pt`, respectively, in the standard document classes.

In the above MWE, [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) provides the colour specification, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: It is possible to leave the caption without the background color, or at least change it to white? (and how to put the caption at the bottom of the picture?)

Answer (score 5):

One solution could be using the package `shaded` as follows:

```
\usepackage{shaded}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.9}

\newenvironment{inline}[2]{
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{shaded}
            \caption{#1}\label{#2}
                \vspace{10pt}%
}{
        \end{shaded}
    \end{figure}
}
```

This will produce a gray background of `\textwidth` width. One could also use:

```
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
```

instead of:

```
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{.9}
```

if the purpose is to produce a horrible orage background. You have all the freedom you need to define the color `shadecolor` in terms of the `color` package.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the `mdframed` package mentioned by Werner the `bgcolor` key of `adjustbox` can also be used to color the background color of a boxed content. Here the `minipage=\linewidth` key must also be used to allow multiple lines (the caption and the image).

For easier comparison (and less work for me ;-) ) I reused Werner's example code. The main difference is that `mdframed` allows for page breaks, but this isn't important in this case because `figures` are never broken across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newenvironment{inline}[3][black!25]{%
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,bgcolor={#1}}% maybe also: margin=x y
    \centering
    \caption{#2}\label{#3}%
    \vspace{10pt}%
}{%
    \end{adjustbox}%
  \end{figure}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{inline}{An image}{image}
  \rule{150pt}{100pt}
\end{inline}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```