# Background color for existing floats (e.g. w/o defining a new environment)?

Tags: floats, color, backgrounds

I'm trying to make all my figures (including caption) backgrounded with a decent color.

I already found these questions with some nice answers:

- *[How to set a background color of figure environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51111/how-to-set-a-background-color-of-figure-environment)*
- *[Rounded corner colored box around figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure)*
- *[Background color boxes around complete figure in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39684/background-color-boxes-around-complete-figure-in-latex)*

But all these answers have in common that they define some new environments or commands that need to be put inside the figures or replace the figures completly.

**Is there a way to put a background color behind *existing* floats without having to change the content of these existing floats?**

Comment: You can use the link answers. Just redefine the environment figure.

Comment: How about background color with [adjustbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\foo#1\normalcolor\vbox\bgroup#2!!{%
\def\@xfloat ##1[##2]{#1%
 \normalcolor
      \hbox\bgroup{\color{yellow}\leaders\vrule\hskip\columnwidth\hskip-\columnwidth}%
      \vbox \bgroup\aftergroup\egroup
#2}}
\expandafter\foo\@xfloat{#1}[#2]!!

\makeatother

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
a\\b\\c
\caption{yes no}
\end{figure}

one two three

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do select the float types (figure, table, ...) for which these apply? For example if I want different colors for figures and tables.

Comment: `\@captype` will be `figure` `table` etc so you could test that or if it is just a matter of colour choice replace `yellow` by `color-\@captype`  and then use `\definecolor` to define colors `color-figure` and `color-table`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what is the meaning of `!!` on the 3rd line of the code?

Comment: @Sigur It's just a token to mark the end of the argument (the end of the expansion of `\@xfloat` anything could be used that is not in the expansion of the macro so long as the same marker is used 6 lines later after the expansion of `\@xfloat`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an elementary implementation using [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) that redefines the `figure` environment (therefore not adapting the usage of `figure` in your document):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mdframed,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,mdframed,xcolor}
\let\oldfigure\figure% Store old figure environment start
\let\endoldfigure\endfigure% Store old figure environment end
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][htbp]% Redefine figure
  {\oldfigure[#1]\mdframed[backgroundcolor=blue!15]}
  {\endmdframed\endoldfigure}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

From here it would be straight forward to apply a different style to a different float (like `table`, for example).

Comment: Tried this, too. Worked well, hence the upvote, but I have accepted the other answer because it does not depend on a package (which could possbibly introduce unwanted side effects).