# Background color for all existing floats（documentclass revtex and aastex）

Tags: floats, positioning, backgrounds, revtex, aastex

The question is a follow-up to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629124/background-color-for-all-existing-floats).

I hope to add the background color to all floats in batches without changing the content of these existing floats. This code works well when the documentclass is article and amsart, but when the documentclass is revtex and aastex There will be problems, how can I solve them?

example of revtex4-1

```
\documentclass[english,aps,prl,amsmath,amssymb,reprint,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\caption{\label{tab1}test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test }
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Model & $\triangle\gamma$ \tabularnewline
\hline 
ATI  & 21.4, 21.6 , 23.8 \tabularnewline
UBB & 31.5 \tabularnewline
UBB & 31.5 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}

\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

example of aastex

```
\documentclass{aastex63}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
header0 & $\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}header1\\ text after linebreak\end{tabular}$ & header2 \\
\midrule
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `revtex4-1.cls` redefines float internal macros, and this document class is obsolete. A patch working for all/most document classes would require much more case-to-case effort than expected. As I already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629223/save-position-information-of-all-existing-floats#comment1569171_629223), what's the big picture/full story of your real demand?

Comment: Hello, my requirement is: I have a large batch of latex files, and I want to save the location information of their pictures and tables. At that time, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106904/background-color-for-existing-floats-e-g-w-o-defining-a-new-environment) told me that I can add background colors to all floats. So my last question asked you how to save the position information of the background frame when adding the background color to all floats. Then I found that this code is not applicable in the aastex and revtex document types, so I asked this new question.