# How to frame a figure in Lyx

Tags: floats, lyx

I use Lyx 2.1.
I want to frame the figures. I inserted a simple box and I put the figure inside it.

But, I encountered these errors :

[image]

Comment: As I asked in the other question, should the caption be included in the frame? Also, LyX is being useless here, so it is totally impossible to know exactly what causes those errors from your screenshot. Create a LyX document that contains only such a figure, export it to LaTeX, and edit your question to include the LaTeX code.

Comment: Also, should the frame be the width of the text, or just enclose the image?

Comment: If I remove the frame, the errors will be deleted. just enclose the image and his legend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three different ways, for three different scenarios.

## 1. Frame tightly enclosing image

Step by step:

1. Add a Figure float, with Insert --> Float --> Figure, or the [image] button on the toolbar.
2. Add a framebox with Insert --> Box --> Simple frame inside the Figure float.
3. Right click the box and choose *Settings.*
4. Set the *Inner box* to *None*, and remove the checkmark from the *Width* box:

   [image]
5. Insert the image *inside* this box, with Insert --> Graphics or the [image] button on the toolbar.

[image]

## 2. Just image inside frame, frame width of the text

If the caption should not be inside the frame, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and add the following:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

This will make all your figures (added with Insert --> Float --> Figure, or the corresponding button on the toolbar) framed.

[image]

If you want the caption a little further away from the frame in this case, replace the three code lines above with

```
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand\fs@boxed{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\setbox\@currbox\vbox{\hbadness10000
    \moveleft3.4pt\vbox{\advance\hsize by6.8pt
      \hrule \hbox to\hsize{\vrule\kern3pt
        \vbox{\kern3pt\box\@currbox\kern3pt}\kern3pt\vrule}\hrule}}}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}%
  \def\@fs@post{}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}

\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

## 3. Both caption and image inside frame

You can use Peter Grill's answer to [Rounded corner colored box around figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31545/rounded-corner-colored-box-around-figure). For a simple black frame, and add this code to the LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFigureBoxStyle}{tikzsetting={draw=black, line width=1pt}}%

 \newcommand\fs@myRoundBox{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
  \def\@fs@pre{\begin{mdframed}[style=myFigureBoxStyle]}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}}%
  \def\@fs@post{\end{mdframed}}\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}

\floatstyle{myRoundBox} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

This will make figures, including the caption, framed.

[image]

Comment: How can I put the caption below the frame?

Comment: @user1936895 Answer edited. Anything missing?

Comment: Thank you very much. I want the caption be farthest from the frame

Comment: @user1936895 What do you mean? Further away from the frame? For which of the three cases?

Comment: 2. Just image inside frame, frame width of the text.I want the caption be farthest from the frame (ie more space between the two)

Comment: @user1936895 I thought that was what you meant, so I edited my answer three hours ago, adding a solution for this. See the code block just after the screenshot under part 2. (By the way, ['farthest'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farthest) means 'most far', you wanted to say 'further'.)

Comment: Hi. Approach 3 no longer works when using subfigures. I get `You can't use \spacefactor in vertical mode.` followed by tons of follow-up errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NameZero912 Apologies, the `\makeatother` shouldn't have been there. Remove it and the `\makeatletter` a few lines further up. LyX adds `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` around the user part of the preamble anyways.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot, that worked. Note that there are new problems when using `mdframed` in Lyx that contains tables in which you have footnotes. I replaced the solution using just `framed`. However, one minor annoyance is that now any text that I originally placed *below* the caption (i.e. from top to bottom I have: figure(s), caption, additional text inside the float) now appears *above* the caption for some reason.

Comment: @NameZero912 Try with `\restylefloat*{figure}` instead of `\restylefloat{figure}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, that did the trick. You're like a wizard :)! Do you have any suggestions how to avoid that the frame is a bit too wide? For instance, if the width of my text is 13 cm (due to my page margins), then a boxed figure (using `framed`) is a bit wider. The text within the figure is also 13cm wide, but between my figure-text and the frame itself there is approx. 3-5 mm of margin. I don't mind the margin per se, but I would rather the box be exactly as wide as `\textwidth`, and the contained content to be scaled appropriately. The box is also too wide even if there is little text

Comment: @NameZero912 No, I just read the manual. You could try modifying to `\def\@fs@pre{\begin{framed}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}}`, and add `\end{minipage}` before `\end{framed}` in the definition of `\@fs@post`.